# How should my users install a Python command line app for Mac?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, command-line

I want to create a command line app which would be run from the Terminal on Mac OS X (and eventually other platforms).

I can make the Python script and have it running in Terminal, etc, but the problem comes for the user. I'd like the user to download the app and install it as one normally would, and then call the app by perhaps typing "appname" directly into Terminal.

How would I go about this? Would I need to wrap my Python file in some kind of Objective-C mini app and install that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple command line app on Mac OS X, you wouldn't need to package it as an OS X application bundle, which is what `py2app` and the deprecated `BundleBuilder` do.  And an app bundle is not the normal way to access a command line utility since the user would have to "reach in" and execute something inside of the bundle.  If you don't have third-party C library dependencies in your app, the simplest way may be to package it as a standard Distutils distribution with a `setup.py`.  Since Apple supplies versions of Python and `setuptools` in recent OS X releases, if you uploaded your app to [the Python Package Index, PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), the user could download and install your app with one command in a terminal window:

```
sudo easy_install your_app_name
```

That will, by default, install the script into `/usr/local/bin` which is included in the default `PATH` for OS X users' shells.  If you don't want to upload it to `PyPI` you could still use `easy_install` to install from a downloaded file or from a URL.  You'll also need to take into account any Python version dependencies and which Pythons Apple makes available with the OS X releases you intend to support.  There are version-specific `easy_install-2.x` commands.

Also, because Distutils and the higher level tools that use it (`pip`, `Distribute`, `setuptools`, et al) are cross-platform, you may not need to do anything to support installation on most other Unix-y distributions.

On the other hand, if your app has Python version-specific dependencies or has third-party library dependencies and you need to support multiple OS X versions such that you cannot use an Apple-supplied Python, then it may be better to use `py2app` and bundle up an application-specific copy of Python.  In that case, perhaps you could have the user double-click on the downloaded app bundle which would run a script to authenticate and create a symlink from `/usr/local/bin` to the appropriate script file within the app bundle.  That has the disadvantage of making the application bundle path-location dependent, though.  There are other, more complicated ways to do something similar without that restriction, if necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the `sudo easy_install` command. You can't uninstall it and it bypasses whatever package manager you're using. If you must do that you should atleast use a virtualenv.

Comment: There is no package manager for the system Python on Mac OS X.

Comment: To be clear, yes, there are other, better more general solutions like `virtualenv` and `pip` but they do not come pre-installed on OS X; `easy_install` does and, for a simple command line script application, that may be sufficient.

Comment: Perhaps `pip` instead of `easy_install`. That atleast has an uninstall option.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

- http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/BundleBuilder
- http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/py2app

Comment: Note that `BundleBuilder` is deprecated and has been removed in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to BundleBuilder and py2app I thought I would mention [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).  It is cross platform and seems to support some large packages (e.g. PyQT and matplotlib) better than py2app.